# How to make a text file from dataframe in a specific way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have this Dataframe in python:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd0px.png)

and I need it to be as a txt file that should be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQVTL.png)

How do I do it? I try with .to_csv and with argument delimiter | but it is not the same as I want.

Comment: please provide your input/output data as formatted text or dataframe constructors

Comment: convert your data frame to numpy array numpy_array = your_dataframe.to_numpy()  and save it using savetxt 
np.savetxt("test_file.txt", numpy_array, fmt = "%d")

Comment: While not really being uncommon, I know no standard formatter for that kind of format. But it is very easy to write that in plain Python. Just have a try, and ask again here if you are struck somewhere...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to write that formatter yourself.

You can start with this.

```
df.to_markdown()
```

**Note**: This is different data from yours as you have not provided text data.

```
|    | ID_1   |   ID_2 | DATE       |   VALUE |
|---:|:-------|-------:|:-----------|--------:|
|  0 | A      |      1 | 2021-11-21 |     0.5 |
|  1 | A      |      2 | 2021-12-19 |     0.5 |
|  2 | A      |      2 | 2021-09-05 |     0.5 |
|  3 | B      |      1 | 2021-11-07 |     0.6 |
|  4 | B      |      1 | 2021-12-05 |     0.6 |
|  5 | B      |      2 | 2021-12-26 |     0.6 |
```

Comment: Thank you! 
(I didnt provided it because it is in a virtual machine that I just can't transfer it to here)